# CSS: Reset "right" property in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

This in the process of making a website compatible with IE7.

The main css file defines a "right" property on for a div.
Using the developer tools in IE7, I can fix a display issue by unchecking that "right" property on that div.
I understand the default property needs to be specified for that div in the ie7 specific stylesheet.

I read "auto" is the default value. Niether that (nor "none", "0") has the same effect as unchecking the property in the developer tools "style" panel.

How should I proceed?
Thanks :)

Comment: Setting the `right` property to 0 should work. Can you make a jsfiddle that replicates this problem? Such as http://jsfiddle.net/DrC66

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) Sadly 0 isn't taken in account. I'll try to reproduce that with jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: replace the "right" property with a "margin-right", which provides the same results (in this case) using recent browsers.
IE7 no longer fails to render the element properly and the margin-right works properly.

Answer (score 1):

what if you just set it to blank. as in ''

Answer (score 1):

to reset a style in jquery you can just do

```
$('#myelementid').css('right','');
```

you could try this and then do inspect element in chrome dev tools or firebug to see how jquery reset this.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks! However it adds a style property, doesn't affect the css itself :( Setting '' using your idea remove the attribute from the element's styles.

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of the `right` property is is `auto`.

If that doesn’t work, you’re most likely experiencing a specificity issue, where another CSS rule takes precedence over the rule you’re editing.

Comment: Must be that 2nd option indeed. Just figured out a workaround that'll do. Thanks for your input!